# IAM S3 replication of data to only accounts that are part of the Organisation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Is there a way to restrict the replication of S3 data to only AWS Accounts that are part of the Organisation ?

I have looked at using IAM Policy, Bucket Policy and Boundaries but i cannot see how to restrict or allow based on destination AWS Account information

Comment: What do you mean by "replication of S3 data"? Are you referring to Cross-Region Replication and Same-Region Replication. Also, how do you define "the Organisation"? Are you using **AWS Organizations**?

Comment: Thats correct we are using AWS Organizations @JohnRotenstein
The scenario I trying to prevent is the data been replicated/copy/moved to a S3 bucket that is outside the Organization, for example a users personal AWS Account.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 objects are private by default. Nobody inside or outside the AWS account can access the data unless permissions are granted.

It is easy to prevent access to **external people** (who do not have credentials for the AWS account) because the only way they can access data is if there are S3 Bucket Policies that permit access, or if there are IAM Roles that they are allowed to assume.

**Internal**, however, will pose more challenges. You say that you want to prevent the data from being copied to a user's personal AWS account. This can be easily accomplished **by not granting access** to the source S3 bucket. However, as soon as they have access for a normal business purpose, they could download/copy the objects however they wish. A copy command is simply reading data from one location and copying to somewhere else, which is indistinguishable from reading data for a normal business purpose.

Some companies go to extreme lengths, such as only granting permission when the data is access via a particular IP address or network connection, which maps to a **room of computers** that have their USB ports and floppy disk drives disabled.

The best method is to *not* grant access to production data. Only allow production apps to access the production data.

**Bottom line:** If you don't want people to have access to data, then **don't grant them access**. However, if you *do* grant access, it would be difficult to limit what they then do with the data.

Comment: thanks for the information @JohnRotenstein.
Downloading the information from S3 to say the PC is restricted
The specific scenario I am trying to prevent is the the Data from an S3 bucket been replicated/move/copy into another S3 bucket that is not part of the Org.
By the sounds of things this is not possible.

Comment: People can't do things if they haven't been granted permission to do them, so it depends on the permissions they have been granted. How are you currently restricting "Downloading the information from S3 to the PC"? Is that via S3 policies?